# Check all values in hash with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have hash that looks like this:

```
{ .user_import_163="100%", .user_import_164="99%"}
```

How in Javascript I can check that all values are equal to 100%?

Comment: How did your hash get into javascript?  This doesn't look like javascript (where they are called `object`s), or ruby, (where they are called hashes).

Comment: I suppose you're asking how to determine whether two given *objects* are equal, aren't you?

Comment: Yes this is a javascript object. Sorry, my bad. So how can I check if all values in this object are equal to  100% ?

Comment: No, it isn't. In JavaScript objects literals look like `{ attr1: "value1", attr2: "value2" }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: @cezar - Most likely, it isn't actual code but a console.log() dump or the source JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another sample:

```
var data = { a: '100%', b: '99%' }

var check = function(obj) {
  var correct = true;

  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] != '100%') correct = false;
  }

  return correct;
}

check(data); // return false
check({ a: '100%', b: '100%' }); // return true
```

Answer (score 3):

> How in Javascript I can check that all values are equal to 100%?

Assuming a valid JavaScript object:

```
var obj = {
    user_import_163: "100%",
    user_import_164: "99%"
};
```

or

```
var obj = {
    ".user_import_163": "100%",
    ".user_import_164": "99%"
};
```

You can do this:

```
if (Object.keys(obj).some(function(k) { return obj[k] !== "100%"; })) {
    // At least one isn't equal to "100%"
} else {
    // All are equal to "100%"
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
snippet.log("(true = at least one property is NOT 100%)");
test(1,
     {
      user_import_163: "100%",
      user_import_164: "99%"
     },
     true
);
test(2,
     {
      user_import_163: "100%",
      user_import_164: "100%"
     },
     false
);

function test(num, obj, expectedResult) {
  var result = Object.keys(obj).some(function(k) {
    return obj[k] !== "100%";
  });
  snippet.log(
    "Test #" + num +
    ": Got " + result +
    ", expected " + expectedResult + " <== " +
    (!result === !expectedResult ? "good" : "ERROR")
  );
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```